# css color rendering different in safari

Tags: css, firefox, safari

I am trying to pick colours for my web app but realizing a huge difference in the way safari renders the stylesheet when compared with firefox or chrome. The red colour in the screenshot is supposed to be #ff3366, however it seems safari chooses to render #ff0036.

I am not sure why I can't find any information on this problem, am I crazy?

I am running 10.9.1 Mavericks

thanks!

[image: safari-firefox comparison]

Comment: Because different browsers use different rendering engines. It's not an issue that you should really be worrying about. After all, ho wmany actual users would look at it in more than one browser.

Comment: Really? It just seems like such a drastic change in the look of the site.. the colours are much more vibrant in safari, I just don't understand why this would not be a more talked about problem among designers..

Comment: Old article: http://css-tricks.com/color-rendering-difference-firefox-vs-safari/

Comment: @Paulie_D The article you link to is about images saved with photoshop including their colour profiles, not html colours rendered. Also the "duplicate" question is about a difference in rendering between firefox and chrome. My problem is within safari. Chrome and Firefox both render the css colour passed to them. Maybe Safari is now suffering from whatever bug chrome used to have?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44825/discussion-between-graeme-and-paulie-d)

Comment: This has been making me crazy, too, because, while the CSS colors are consistent with how images are being rendering in either browser, the Firefox & Chrome rendering is much closer to what I'm looking for from a brand perspective AND are closer to what I'm seeing on my iPhone, where there's no option to tweak colors. So the more vivid, redder orange I'm seeing in Safari in OS X is the anomaly.

Comment: My late 2011 MacBook Air is hooked up to a Viewsonic monitor with sRGB as the color profile. Safari & Firefox are the same side by side there, a truer orange. It's the "Color LCD" profile on the MacBook Air that's off, but choosing sRGB on that screen makes everything much, much bluer than the Viewsonic monitor.

Comment: @Paulie_D The article you linked to establishes Chrome as the anomaly, not Safari. I'm seeing Firefox & Chrome behave the same with Safari as the anomaly, similar to the original post here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but there’s really nothing you can do about it.

- Each browser has its own rendering engine, and they render colors differently.
- Users rarely visit a website in more than one browser, and as a result will probably  not notice.
- As I said, there’s nothing you can do to change it. Just pick a color that looks fine in the different browsers and continue. I wish I could offer you a better answer but that’s really all there is to it!

Comment: It's unfortunate there is no code given in the OP.  While this answer has some truth to it - it's definitely not complete.  Having a color profile assigned to an image (which is honored by some browsers and ignored by others), for example, can be one cause of this type of inconsistency - and that's something that can absolutely be easily changed.  So it's not really accurate to just attribute all color differences to some unnamed difference in the rendering engine that cannot be adjusted.

Comment: Also both Safari and Chrome use Webkit as the rendering engine so they are the same rendering engine. We have the same problem with a site where on Chrome and Firefox an orange is rendered as a nice bright orange but on Safari it is like a muddy brown colour. Sorry Apple but Safari is quickly becoming your IE!!! :-(

Comment: @BradPeabody I guess I'm missing your point, this question has nothing to do with how images are rendered, rather a div with a background colour.

Comment: @Graeme If the background color is actually coming from CSS, you're right.  But that's why I mentioned seeing the code, because I have observed this exact issue with images due to color profile differences.  The OP implies that a CSS background color is being used but doesn't explicitly state that.  I suspect it might be an image with an alternative color profile (i.e. if those red boxes are actually images).  It would explain the issue.