# CSS Color Rendering in Safari

Tags: css, colors, safari

So I am using #e5592e as a background colour.

In Safari it renders significantly brighter than in Firefox or Chrome. To the point that I need to change it.

However, I can't seen to find a css hack that allows me to target Safari only.

Is there a more elegant solution anyone is aware of?

edit: Adding code to demonstrate the problem;

```
<html>


<style>
p {

    background-color: #e5592e;
    min-height: 500px;
}

</style>

<body>
<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Not the page in question but still demonstrates the same problem.

For me, the colour here is much brighter in Safari than in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue - `#e5592e` looks the same to me either way. There might be some browser-specific CSS rules that apply to the background-color of the target element that are working with in Safari, but not Chrome/Firefox or vice versa.  Can you post all of the relevant code and CSS needed to recreate the issue?

Comment: Added an example. If i view that page in safari, the colour is much brighter, much more red.

Comment: Actually, I guess you're right!  I didn't perceive a difference but I am seeing [questions about the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001015/css-color-rendering-different-in-safari).